How to write a certain hooked bijective arrow in latex

How do you write the bijection arrow between A and B which is shown above? Where one arrow symbolizes injectivity.
I'm uncertain where the notation came from, but I have seen it in some textbooks (though I don't remember which or when). I haven't either been able to find sources referencing this symbol.
The only similar symbol is the \hookleftarrow or \hookrightarrow arrows: $\hookleftarrow$ and $\hookrightarrow$.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you know TeXify?

@Mensch Nope, my knowledge in overleaf stretches from and ends with searching and finding. I've tried DeTextify but the tool does not find the desired result, just the regular bijection arrow.

Your symbol not exist.

This is similar to jlab's answer but with some twists:

the bottom arrow is \hookrightarrow rotated (around its center) by 180 degrees;
the top arrow is bumped a bit to the right and the bottom arrow to the left, to visually compensate the hooks;
the vertical space between the two arrows is a bit shrinked;
the size correctly changes in sub/superscripts and starts from standard text/display style;
the second argument to \mathpalette is a vertical adjustment, see later.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hookleftrightarrows}{%
  \mathrel{% we want a relation symbol
    \mathpalette\hookleftrightarrows@{2}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\hookleftrightarrows@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \sbox\z@{$#1\mkern#2mu$}
    \ialign{##\cr
      $#1\mkern1mu\hookrightarrow$\cr
      \noalign{\kern-\wd\z@}
      \rotatebox[origin=C]{180}{$#1\mkern1mu\hookrightarrow$}\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$A \hookleftrightarrows B$

$A_{\hookleftrightarrows}$

\end{document}


With different fonts, the vertical adjustment might need some tweak. For instance, the same code with newtx would produce

If I change \mathpalette\hookleftrightarrows@{2} into \mathpalette\hookleftrightarrows@{4} the output becomes


The upper symbol is \hookrightarrow. You can create the lower from the first with a rotation of 180°
\rotatebox{180}{$\hookrightarrow$}

\rotatebox is a command from the graphicx package (the symbol is also directly provided as \lhookleftarrow in some packages like MnSymbol).
You can draw the two symbols, in \scriptstyle size, one over the other with something like
\ialign {#\crcr%
    $\scriptstyle\hookrightarrow$\crcr%
      \noalign { \nointerlineskip }%
      \rotatebox{180}{$\scriptstyle\hookrightarrow$}\cr}

Finally add \vcenter to center it on the math axis, \mathrel to adjust the spacing. Define a new command with the whole
\newcommand*{\hookleftrightarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\ialign {##\crcr%
    $\scriptstyle\hookrightarrow$\crcr%
      \noalign { \nointerlineskip }%
      \rotatebox{180}{$\scriptstyle\hookrightarrow$}\cr}}}%
}

(where # in the \ialign should be doubled, as we're inside \newcommand).
Result:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\hookleftrightarrows}{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\ialign {##\crcr%
    $\scriptstyle\hookrightarrow$\crcr%
      \noalign { \nointerlineskip }%
      \rotatebox{180}{$\scriptstyle\hookrightarrow$}\cr}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$ A \hookleftrightarrows B $

\end{document}


